# Can Swagelok SS ferrule be reused?

Tags: hydraulics, pipelines, connections

At times, the Swagelok SS Ferrules gets crimped tight into the SS pipe. In those cases, can these ferrules be forcefully removed and reused?

Or was this a result of faulty installation?

Comment: No, it can’t be re-used reliably, but you may consider the possibilty of soldering it.

Comment: Will that still work for the same pressure range? Or would it better to cut the ferrule and use new ones?

Comment: Use new - why mess around...

Comment: I still use and prefer soldering copper fittings to copper pipe...

Comment: My bad, I will edit the question for more information. My question is more oriented towards SS.

Comment: Swagelok is for high pressure ( eg.1000 psi +) stainless tubing applications ; when ever I saw them.

Comment: I expect if you can readly get it off then it wasnt torqued properly to begin with.

Comment: @agentp - aint the ferrules designed for multiple assembly and disassembly? Can't it be taken off, and then again put on with ease, unlike a permanent weld?

Comment: the fitting can be disassembled. The ferrule and tube are permanently deformed on first assembly and stay together.

Comment: So if one finds that there is still leaks, then how to remove if the ferrule gets crimped tightly?

Comment: I think we have an "xy" question ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem ).  If your *actual question* is how to fix a leak you should edit the question or pose a new one.